# Adding a connection to a SQL Server 2008, what do I need to open up?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, firewall, portforwarding, windows-firewall

I'm trying to add a Data Connection in Visual Studio 2010 to a SQL Server 2008 database at a given IP (thru internet). What ports do I need to open up and forward to make the magic happen?

Any settings in the SQL Server I need to set to allow external connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 1433 is the default one used.

See [TCP/IP port numbers required to communicate to SQL over a firewall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932) for more details.

> The default SQL Server port is 1433, and client ports are assigned a random value between 1024 and 5000.

And:

> The port doesn't need to be 1433, but 1433 is the official Internet Assigned Number Authority (IANA) socket number for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

to to sql server configuration manager toi check the port being used and open that port.

Also, on Sql Server Management Studio, right click the instance -> Properties -> Connections -> Check "Allow remote connections to this server".